# Geometric Distribution - Probability of losing money with gambling - Is my solution correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have no way to check if my solution to this problem is correct or not, so I would greatly appreciate if someone would check if my procedure for solving it is correct! I'm preparing for an exam, hence, it is important for me. Thank you anyone willing to spare some time for this!

In a casino, you gamble as long as you lose, and you stop once you have won. You gamble 100 euros each time. Winning earns you 500 euros. The chance of winning is 1/5 at each round. What is the probability you will lose money at the end?

So, since this is a case of a repeated independent trials until success is reached, this should be a Geometric distribution with paramenter p=0.2.

> What we are looking for is that a win does not happen before the 6th
>   round, in other words, $P(k≥6) = 1-P(k≤5)=1 -
> > [P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+(P5)]$

$P(k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$

$P(1)=0.2$
$P(2)=0.16$
$P(3)=0.128$
$P(4)=0.1024$
$P(5)=0.08192$

Summing all up and we obtain:

> $1 - 0.67232 = 0.32768$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems correct, but for a geometric distribution we have that $P(X \gt x)=(1-p)^{x}$. So your problem has solution $P(k \gt 5) = (1-0.2)^5=0.32768$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know this formula but seems very useful and helpful!

Comment: Yes, it is due to the fact that the probability of succeeding after $x$ trials requires one to fail $x$ times first.

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't allow me to do that right after you posted and I forgot to come back and do so.